# computed function in vuejs dose not work with me

Tags: vuejs2

I'm new with vue.js and have a problem,
I have a computed function that alerts a Word reversed,
I made this function working on clicking a button but it works on page loading so what is the problem.
this is the vue.js code,

```
new Vue({
el: '#computed',
data: {
    word: 'welcome',
},
computed: {
    alertRev: function() {
        // get the word reversed
        alert (this.word.split('').reverse().join(''));
    },
}});
```

And this is HTML code:

```
<div id="computed">
    <button @click="alertRev">reverse the word</button>
</div>
```

And this is jsFiddle link [Link to code](https://jsfiddle.net/a3as9xp8/3/#&togetherjs=DmsQEzhjsb)

Comment: A computed is a property, not a method. When you open your fiddle, it alerts the reverse, because it is calculated when the Vue is created. But a computed is not a method. That's why when you click, nothing happens. If you want click to do the alert, then make a method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, bert,
 i appreciate that

Comment: That collaboration option on jsFiddle was pretty cool. I didn't know it could do that :)

Comment: yeah it's very cool, it helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

As @BertEvans indicated, a method will achieve what you want to do.

My understanding is that a computed property would typically return a result from a function, as opposed to performing an action, such as an alert. Shamelessly modified example from Vuejs docs (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#computed',
  data: {
    word: 'welcome',
  },
  computed: {
    reversedMessage: function() {
      // get the word reversed, no alert
      return this.word.split('').reverse().join('');
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="computed" style="font-family: arial;">
  Type the word: <input type="text" v-model="word">
  <br />
  <br /> Reversed: {{ reversedMessage }}
</div>
```

The method example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#computed',
  data: {
    word: 'welcome',
  },
  methods: {
    alertRev: function() {
      // get the word reversed
      alert(this.word.split('').reverse().join(''));
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="computed">
  Word: {{ word }}
  <br />
  <br />
  <button @click="alertRev">Reverse the word (alert)</button>
</div>
```

As an aside, computed properties aren't very handy with asynchronous operations.

Hope this doesn't highlight that you could write what I know about Vuejs on the back of a postage stamp with a wet mop.